# React Native Cache issue while creating new project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs, expo-go

Step 1
First I created the project with the command `npx create-expo-app --template`.

Step 2
Under the project I run the command `npx expo`.

Now it keep giving the below message.

> › Detected a change in `babel.config.js`. Restart the server to see
> the new results. You may need to clear the bundler cache with the
> `--clear` flag for your changes to take effect.

However, it shows the QR code on terminal to open in Expo Go in Android but it just loading in mobile and crashed after sometime.

I have tried clearing the cache with following commands but not working and still showing the error.

```
react-native start --reset-cache
npm start -- --reset-cache
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```